# Angular 11 library module is imported but not used in consuming app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

I'm developing an Angular library to contain services, pipes, directives, etc. that will be shared across multiple Angular projects in my company. I have three services implemented so far, and the library project builds just fine. However, when I import the module in an app that uses the library, I don't get errors in VSCode or the console, but my DOM is totally blank. The services also work fine when importing the .ts files directly in the project folder, but the Angular docs say specifically to *not* do this, and to only import them from the built module. I also made sure that the "Utilities" module import maps correctly in the .tsconfig to the built project folder. Please help!

Here is the library module definition:

```js
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UtilitiesConfig } from './interfaces/utilities-config.interface';
import { APIService } from './services/api.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { JWTService } from './services/jwt.service';
import { LogService } from './services/log.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    APIService,
    LogService,
    AuthenticationService
  ]
})
export class UtilitiesModule {

  public static forRoot(environment: UtilitiesConfig): ModuleWithProviders<UtilitiesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: UtilitiesModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'environment',
          useValue: environment
        },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: JWTService,
          multi: true
        },
        APIService,
        LogService,
        AuthenticationService
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the module definition for the consuming app:

```js
import { UtilitiesModule } from 'utilities';

let imports: any[] = [
  UtilitiesModule.forRoot({
    ...
  })
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  imports
})
export class ConsumerModule {

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    const ConsumerElement = createCustomElement(ConsumerButtonComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('ConsumerApp', ConsumerElement);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the issue. The library needs to be linked using `npm link`, and the consuming app needs to link to the library. Since all of my projects are contained within an angular (npm) workspace, I had to do it a little differently.

From angular workspace root directory:

```sh
cd projects/utilities
npm link
cd ../.. (back to workspace root)
npm link dist/utilities
```

Also be sure to run the library in watch mode when developing with either the library, consuming app, or both:

```
cd projects/utilities
ng build --project=utilities --watch
```

Good luck and I hope this helps somebody out there!